# Magento2 coupon code not working

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes

I have generated multiple coupon codes inside the same rule. However, one coupon code is not working. I tried to add that coupon code and it was working but suddenly it stopped working. I also checked in the database and it is not used. It is also not expired.
All other coupons are working fine under the same rule.
Is it stored inside a customer session or something like that?